# How to horizontally align 2 Divs close to each other

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using Twitter bootsrap 2.3 in my Razor view

How can I horizontally align the below divs beside each other to get the effect similar to a  table with a row and 2 cells. Divs should be to the left and right of each other.

```
        <div id="Main">

            <div id="left">
                <label><input type="checkbox" /> Left Side</label>

                <label><input type="checkbox" /> Left Side</label>

                <label>  <input type="checkbox" checked/> Left Side</label>

            </div>

            <div id="right">                 

                <label><input type="checkbox" /> Right side</label>

                <label><input type="checkbox" /> Right side</label>

                <label>  <input type="checkbox" checked/> Right side</label>

                </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="Main">
        <div id="right" style="float:left;">                 

            <label><input type="checkbox" /> Right side</label>

            <label><input type="checkbox" /> Right side</label>

            <label>  <input type="checkbox" checked/> Right side</label>

            </div>


        <div id="left" style="float:left;">
            <label><input type="checkbox" /> Left Side</label>

            <label><input type="checkbox" /> Left Side</label>

            <label>  <input type="checkbox" checked/> Left Side</label>

        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: Got them to the left and right. Thank you. How can I get them close to each other

Comment: use float:left on both to get them close together, and you can add a margin-left to the right div if you don't want them to be too close

Comment: @milligran  imbask commented the right answer, you can do mine one also and bring them close by using "width property" of css

Comment: Can you edit your answer. None of your suggestions got them close to each other

Comment: have a look, it is based on the comment of @imbask

Answer (score 1):

You can float left DIV by setting it's float style to left:

```
<div id="left" style="float:left">
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GC4GY/

P.S. You don't have to put checkbox inside of label, you can user label's "for" attribute instead. E.g. you can change

```
<label>  <input type="checkbox" checked/> Left Side</label>
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk3" checked="true" /><label for="chk3"> Left Side</label>
```

Comment: bot the elements in the left and right are not label for. They are a completely different set of elements

Answer (score 0):

working [fiddle](http://bootply.com/80628) with twitter bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>
                Heading
            </h2>

            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus
                ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo
                sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed
                odio dui.</p>
            <p> <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a>

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>
                Heading
            </h2>

            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus
                ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo
                sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed
                odio dui.</p>
            <p> <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a>

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```